# Open source flash player software

Tags: open-source

I need recommendation on a reliable open source flash player software that can be used to play flash videos on a website. I have tried the osflv player but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example of an attempt to re-implement the Flash player is the [Ruffle](https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle/) project, though it is still in early development.

However, it would be best to avoid using Flash technology on your website if possible. Alternative options include re-exporting the content as HTML5 or a video in Adobe Animate (if you still have the source file for the video) or making a high-quality screen recording of your video and embedding that on your website.

If you are simply attempting to view Flash content, remember that Flash can be re-enabled through your browser settings until mid-to-late 2020. In addition, there is a standalone desktop [Flash Player projector](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) that can also be used to play SWF files, provided you're willing to take a quick look at the source code of the webpage containing the Flash video/animation to locate the URL of the SWF file. Many Flash games are also being archived by the [Flashpoint](https://bluemaxima.org/flashpoint/) project.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this project . I already used this project and there was no problem

https://github.com/komeilkma/flarevideo

Answer (score 0):

I retorted to using the plain HTML5 video element and it worked perfectly, click on the link to see how it works [HTML5 Video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).

Comment: Welcome savageAfiz! Please provide more details on how this answered your question.  Thanks!

Comment: Since I was learning HTML and CSS at the time, I taught it fit to use plain HTML to embed the video on the Web page, please show me how to answer questions correctly here. Thanks!